# asp mvc deployment with msbuild and rake

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, msbuild, rake

I have an asp mvc project. I'm wondering, what's the difference between building the solution and then copying bin and all other views/scripts/images/style sheets and publishing (besides the obvious work of copying files). I'm asking because i want to automate my deployment with rake and I can't use web deployment because it's not compatible with mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Visual Studio and settings, Publishing typically does two main things **in addition to** the build

- Packages the solution
  -- usually into some standard format (WebDeploy, Web Project)
- Automates deployment
  -- typically hooks something like MSdeploy ("web deploy") to synchronize the site with a local or remote IIS setting

So in terms of what you are deploying, *there is no difference*.  The build and output files are the same.  Publishing is simply allowing a developer a simple path of packaging + deploy, which you are handling with rake.

Answer (score 0):

BTW Have you looked [Uppercut](http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/) this tool could be very useful in your build process.